# Swift - adding a constant, accepting argument and returning value

Tags: swift, class, methods, constants

I'm working through the Swift book from Apple and I have a scenario where I have this code

```
class Shape {
    var numberOfSides = 0
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
}
```

The above code works fine in the playground.
The question then asks - **Add a constant property with let, and add another method that takes an argument.** and so I do the following:

```
class Shape {
    var numberOfSides = 0
    let color = "red"
    func simpleDescription() -> String {
        return "A shape with \(numberOfSides) sides."
    }
    func colorDescription() -> String {
        return "This shape is of color \(color)."
    }
}
```

My string "This shape is...." is not returned at all.
There is no error thrown and there is no change from what is returned in the first piece of code.

I have obviously searched GitHub for solutions and tried to understand but in this case, the problem is I don't understand why my own specific solution doesn't work.

What do I need to change here and why?

Comment: Are you calling somewhere the `colorDescription()` function?

Comment: I am not and I have considered that but I am not calling the simpleDescription() either. However, the playground returns the string expected for simpleDescription() . Is it implied that simpleDescription() is called by default in swift / playground. I've just tried calling colorDescription()  but I don't get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct and returns `This shape is of color red.` using this

```
let shape = Shape()
let colorDescription = shape.colorDescription()
```

The Swift Tour provides this sample code for `simpleDescription()`

> ```
> var shape = Shape()
> shape.numberOfSides = 7
> var shapeDescription = shape.simpleDescription()
> ```

which does the same: create the instance and call the method.

Comment: I assume you mean "is" correct. In which case, this issue is most likely with the playground functionality that I am using.

Comment: You probably have more code in the Playground than the pure class.